# Adding content on top of webcam video i.e. color overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I'm trying to add a blue color overlay to my full screen video tag that's pulling the video feed from the users webcam (using JS to do this.) I'm unable to get the blue overlay to appear on top of the video, as it displays behind it, and if the div isn't set to absolute, the video stops being full screen - any thoughts?

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
<div class="overlay--blue">
    <video id="videoElement" class="fullscreen-bg__video"autoplay="true"></video>
</div>
</div>

.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}

.overlay--blue {
    background-color:rgba(19, 186, 228, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving `.overlay--blue` a `z-index`? Maybe 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `#videoElement` is a child of `.overlay--blue`, `#videoElement` will by default be shown on top of `.overlay--blue`.
If you want the video to be shown behind the overlay, you can either give it a negative z-index (`z-index: -1;`). You can also edit the HTML by moving the video outside the overlay, before it, like so:

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video id="videoElement" class="fullscreen-bg__video"autoplay="true"></video>
    <div class="overlay--blue"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yup, giving fullscreen-bg__video a z-index of -1 worked. Thanks!